Is there a way to limit a Impl block to implement another trait?
I have a trait
pub trait LocationProvider<T>
    where T: Into<DateTime<Utc>>
{

    fn get_location(&self, time: T) -> Option<Location>;

    fn get_locations(&self, time_range: (T, T)) -> Vec<Location>;

}

I created an implementation for the trait
impl<T> LocationProvider<T> for XXXLocationProvider
where
    T: Into<DateTime<Utc>>,
{
    fn get_location(&self, _time: T) -> Option<Location> {
        xxx...
    }

    fn get_locations(&self, time_range: (T, T)) -> Vec<Location> {
        xxx...
    }
}

Now, I want all struct implements LocationProvider also implementing IntoIterator<&T> so I can iterate it using for loop, how to achieve the target?
I tried using supertraits, but I can't make it compiled.
My try:
pub trait LocationProvider<'a, T>: IntoIterator<Item = &'a Location>
    where T: Into<DateTime<Utc>>
{

    fn get_location(&self, time: T) -> Option<Location>;

    fn get_locations(&self, time_range: (T, T)) -> Vec<Location>;

}

// I want to iterate XXXLocationProvider by shared reference,
// so I implement this
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a XXXLocationProvider {
    type Item = &'a Location;

    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, Location>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.locations.iter()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> LocationProvider<'a, T> for XXXLocationProvider
where
    T: Into<DateTime<Utc>>,
{
    fn get_location(&self, _time: T) -> Option<Location> {
       xxx...
    }

    fn get_locations(&self, time_range: (T, T)) -> Vec<Location> {
       xxx...
    }
}

the compile error is:
error[E0277]: `xxx_location_provider::XXXLocationProvider` is not an iterator
  --> src/xxx_location_provider.rs:55:41
   |
55 | impl<'a, T> LocationProvider<'a, T> for xxxLocationProvider
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `xxx_location_provider::xxxLocationProvider` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `xxx_location_provider::xxxLocationProvider`, which is required by `xxx_location_provider::xxxLocationProvider: IntoIterator`
   = help: the trait `IntoIterator` is implemented for `&'a xxx_location_provider::xxxLocationProvider`
   = note: required for `xxx_location_provider::xxxLocationProvider` to implement `IntoIterator`
note: required by a bound in `location_provider::LocationProvider`
  --> src/location_provider.rs:5:49
   |
5  | pub trait LocationProvider<'a, T>: IntoIterator<Item = &'a Location>
   |    


Note that you probably want to move the generic parameter on the methods.

This is likely a XY problem. You can use any trait that is implemented for XXXLocationProvider in impl<T> LocationProvider<T> for XXXLocationProvider already, without any additional trait bounds on the impl.

@cafce25 I'd like to force all implementation of LocationProvider to implement IntoIterator<Item = &'a Location>, like interface inheritance in Java.

You impled IntoIterator for a reference to XXXLocationProvider, but the trait requires it for owned value. Which of them do you want?

@ChayimFriedman I want the trait requires it for reference value

tl;dr where for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator<Item = &'a Location> but it might not be as useful as you think

@cafce25 In fact, I solved the problem using the way you mentiond, but as https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html say, the method may not very common (There aren't many places outside of the Fn traits where we encounter HRTBs, and even for those we have a nice magic sugar for the common cases.). So I'm curious if there is a better way?

This isn't a common case.

An other (maybe better) way would be to drop the supertrait bounds, and add these bounds where you actually need them. There are exceptions, but in general it is good practice to reduce the bounds at the definition of an item to those that are actually useful to define it, and introduce those bounds at the implementation level where you need them.

@jthulhu ok, I might have been influenced too much by Java.

For now the generic in unnecessary and I don't think you really want it, since with the generic, T can only be on of type of data,
thus, using impl Into<DataTime<Utc>> is the better option for this case, thus I removed it.
To implement iter() and iter_mut() you will need to create your own data type to hold on to the data during iteration i.e. LocationIter and LocationIterMut
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

/// Temp Struct of Location
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Location {
    pub id: i32,
    pub datetime: DateTime<Utc>,
}

/// The Location Provider Trait
/// I delete the generic T since it is not needed and
/// when I encounter problem when have it
pub trait LocationProvider<'a>: IntoIterator<Item = Location> {
    fn get_location(&self, time: impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>) -> Option<Location>;
    fn get_locations(
        &self,
        time_range: (impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>, impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>),
    ) -> Vec<Location>;
    fn iter(&'a self) -> LocationIter;
    fn iter_mut(&'a mut self) -> LocationIterMut;
}

/// Location Provider Struct
pub struct XXXLocationProvider {
    pub locations: Vec<Location>,
}

/// Implementation of IntoIterator
impl IntoIterator for XXXLocationProvider {
    type Item = Location;
    type IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<Location>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.locations.into_iter()
    }
}

/// Data Structure for iter_mut()
pub struct LocationIterMut<'a> {
    locations: std::slice::IterMut<'a, Location>,
}
impl<'a> Iterator for LocationIterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut Location;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.locations.next()
    }
}

/// Data Structure for iter()
pub struct LocationIter<'a> {
    locations: std::slice::Iter<'a, Location>,
}
impl<'a> Iterator for LocationIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a Location;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.locations.next()
    }
}

/// Implementation of Location for XXXLocationProvider
impl<'a> LocationProvider<'a> for XXXLocationProvider {
    fn get_location(&self, _time: impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>) -> Option<Location> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn get_locations(
        &self,
        time_range: (impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>, impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>),
    ) -> Vec<Location> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> LocationIterMut {
        LocationIterMut {
            locations: self.locations.iter_mut(),
        }
    }
    fn iter(&self) -> LocationIter {
        LocationIter {
            locations: self.locations.iter(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let locations: Vec<Location> = vec![
        Location {
            id: 1,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 32).unwrap(),
        },
        Location {
            id: 2,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 33).unwrap(),
        },
        Location {
            id: 3,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 34).unwrap(),
        },
    ];

    let mut xxx_location_provider = XXXLocationProvider { locations };

    for location in xxx_location_provider.iter_mut() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");
    
    for location in xxx_location_provider.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");
    
    for location in xxx_location_provider.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");
}

Maybe not Implementing IntoIterator, iter(), iter_mut()
If you LocationProvider is a collection of Location, may be it's a better idea to implement Deref<Vec<Location>>, and DerefMut<Vec<Location>>
Example
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Location {
    pub id: i32,
    pub datetime: DateTime<Utc>,
}

pub trait LocationProvider<'a>:
    Deref<Target = Vec<Location>> + DerefMut<Target = Vec<Location>>
{
    fn get_location(&self, time: impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>) -> Option<Location>;
    fn get_locations(
        &self,
        time_range: (impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>, impl Into<DateTime<Utc>>),
    ) -> Vec<Location>;
}

pub struct XXXLocationProvider {
    pub locations: Vec<Location>,
}

impl XXXLocationProvider {
    fn into_iter(self) -> std::vec::IntoIter<Location>{
        self.locations.into_iter()
    }
}

impl Deref for XXXLocationProvider {
    type Target = Vec<Location>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.locations
    }
}

impl DerefMut for XXXLocationProvider {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.locations
    }
}

fn main() {
    let locations: Vec<Location> = vec![
        Location {
            id: 1,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 32).unwrap(),
        },
        Location {
            id: 2,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 33).unwrap(),
        },
        Location {
            id: 3,
            datetime: DateTime::from_timestamp_millis(1 << 34).unwrap(),
        },
    ];

    let mut xxx_location_provider = XXXLocationProvider { locations };

    for location in xxx_location_provider.iter_mut() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");

    for location in xxx_location_provider.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");

    for location in xxx_location_provider.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", location);
    }
    println!("");
}

